# 3 monitors hooked to laptop: main screen extended to 2nd and 3rd duplicates 2nd

Tags: multiple-monitors

Right now, I have my laptop using two screens: the laptop screen and 2nd monitor.  The 2nd monitor extends the desktop.  I would like to be able to hook up a 3rd monitor to duplicate only what the 2nd screen displays.  Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: This is impossible to answer properly without knowing the model of the laptop and the operating system installed (well, it is possible to answer, but the answer is "maybe").  You could probably do it with a splitter in the worst case but that maybe isn't needed.

Comment: There are a few laptops that can support 3 monitors natively. For example, anything with Nvidia Optimus (there may be exceptions to that, but my XPS l502x works fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically speaking, you should be able get a splitter that takes the input going to the screen you want to duplicate and gives the signal to both monitors. Identical or near identical monitors may be necessary.

Many video cards support 2 monitor outputs max (even if they have say 4 connections) which is most likely the case with a laptop.

ie, something like this: [http://www.amazon.com/HDMI-Splitter-Premium-Cable/dp/B000FMJLQC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FMJLQC)

Comment: Thanks Shinrai and Enigma.  I had a feeling that using a splitter was the answer. Just wasn't sure.

Comment: You could go as far as doing something like this: http://lifehacker.com/5851902/turn-a-low+powered-laptop-into-a-gaming-machine-with-an-external-video-card-dock - or some other external video card solution.